# How to instrument Python AST for tracing store operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

[My debugger](http://thonny.org) uses AST instrumentation to get notifications for all logical steps of code execution (including steps in expression evaluation).

There is one step I'm not able to pin down -- the moment when for-loop is just about to assign new value to the loop variable.

Inside `For`-node the loop variable (or something more complicated) is represented with an expression inside `target` attribute. This expression has `ctx` attribute set to `ast.Store()`. I don't know how to trace the usage of this node.

As a special case, I could replace simple loop variables with indexing to `locals()`:

```
for locals()["i"] in range(10):
    print(i)
```

This would give me a `ctx=ast.Load()` node inside the `ctx=ast.Store()` node and I know how to trace this. Unfortunately this won't scale to more complex targets.

How does the interpreter use these `ctx=ast.Store()` expressions? Can I somehow instrument them directly to get notified when interpreter performs the store operation?

Comment: Umm, what do you mean by "instrument"?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, I meant "adding some synthetic code to the original code". In this case I want to add some kind of tracing code which gets executed when Python executes (or is about to execute) a store operation.

Comment: So you just want to add an AST node as the first instruction in the loop?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, If you meant first instruction in for body, then not really. I already can trace the moment before executing the first statement in for-body. I want to visualize the state before loop variable gets its (next) value.

Comment: Okay, I see. I guess you could rewrite the loop and do the assignment to the loop variable manually. But I have to admit that I don't know what the difference between `Load` and `Store` is. Why (and how) can you do it with `Load`, but not with `Store`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, For example I can wrap a Load-expression node inside a function call. If I try to do the same with Store-expression, interpreter gives me `ValueError: expression which can't be assigned to in Store context`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to rewrite the `for` loop so that the assignment targets a temporary variable and insert your tracing code into the loop body. For example, a loop like this:

```
for foo.x in range(3):
    print(foo.x)
```

could be rewritten to this:

```
for _temp in range(3):
    print('loop variable will be set to', _temp)
    foo.x = _temp
    print(foo.x)
```

For this purpose, we implement a [`NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer):

```
class ForLoopRewriter(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, nodes_to_insert):
        super().__init__()
        self.nodes_to_insert = nodes_to_insert

    def visit_For(self, node):
        # redirect the assignment to a usually invalid variable name so it
        # doesn't clash with other variables in the code
        target = ast.Name('@loop_var', ast.Store())

        # insert the new nodes
        loop_body = self.nodes_to_insert.copy()

        # then reassign the loop variable to the actual target
        reassign = ast.Assign([node.target], ast.Name('@loop_var', ast.Load()))
        loop_body.append(reassign)

        # visit all the ast nodes in the loop body
        for n in node.body:
            loop_body.append(self.visit(n))

        # make a new For node and return it
        new_node = ast.For(target, node.iter, loop_body, node.orelse)
        ast.fix_missing_locations(new_node)
        return new_node
```

Which can be used like this:

```
code = '''
class Foo:
    @property
    def x(self):
        pass

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print('Setting x')

foo = Foo()
itr = (print('yielding', x) for x in range(1))

for foo.x in itr:
    pass
'''

tree = ast.parse(code)
tracing_code = ast.parse('print("Your tracing code")').body
tree = ForLoopRewriter(tracing_code).visit(tree)
codeobj = compile(tree, 'foo.py', 'exec')
exec(codeobj)

# output:
# yielding 0
# Your tracing code
# Setting x
```

Comment: Great idea! This solves my case perfectly.
I still hope that someone posts also more info about how to use `ctx=ast.Store()` expressions